# AWS error your account is not a member of an organization

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to AWS. I am trying to learn it by doing. I have a root user and an IAM user with admin rights and many other rights.

I deployed a example simple stack by CDK. I followed some online tutorials. The Deployment was successful by cdk.

I log in to the AWS console by the browser. I navigate to CloudFormation and clicked Stacks. I got this error:-

```
Your account is not a member of an organization. (Service: AWSOrganizationsV20161128; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AWSOrganizationsNotInUseException; Request ID: 129910c4-b89c-4318-b56f-7f753e76d475; Proxy: null)
```

I got the same error for both the root user and IAM user. How do I fix it?

Note that I don't have any AWS organization. I just signup for a fresh AWS account. Just to make sure, I checked the AWS organization, I don't have any organization exist.

After the cdk redeploy:-

[image]

Comment: You should provide more information about the Cloudformation template. This looks like a stackset.

Comment: Regardless of any CDK deployment, as a root user, I should have access right to CloudFormation StackSets. I think even if I wouldn't try to deploy anything. I could have the same error.

Comment: As I mentioned I tried an online tutorial. I deploy this without any modificaiton. https://github.com/CSDose/simple-springboot-service-aws

Comment: Are you sure you didn't click `Stacksets` instead of `Stacks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackSets are only available for AWS Organizations. They allow users to deploy CloudFormation stacks across multiple accounts in an organization. If you try to access StackSets in the AWS Console and you're not a member of an organization, you will get this error, which is expected.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html